# Adding DictHeader with corresponding values to the existing table

Tags: python, api, csv

I'm iterating API requests for each row of the input CSV file. And I want to add API output results to the existing CSV file.

### Input

[image]

### Desired output

As you can see, I added three headers with corresponding results (latitude, longitude, coordinates)

[image]

However, I'm finding difficulty with writing the right query for this. Below is the best I could do.

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_50000_melissa_joined_dropna - Copy2.csv",delimiter=',', na_values="nan")

# Output

with open(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_50000_melissa_joined_dropna - Copy2.csv", 'r') as csvin, open (r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_50000_melissa_joined_dropna - Copy3.csv", 'w', newline='') as out:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvin)
    fieldnames = csvreader.fieldnames + ["latitude","longitude","coordinates"]
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames)
    csvwriter.writeheader()

    # Iterating requests for each row
    for row in df.itertuples():
      output = client.geocode(str(row.addressline1) + ', ' + str(row.city) + ', ' + str(row.state) + ', ' + str(row.postalcode)).coords
      cord = '(' + str(output[0]) + ', '+ str(output[1]) + ')'

      for node, row in enumerate(csvreader, 3):
          csvwriter.writerow(dict(3, {'latitude': output[0], 'longitude': output[1], 'coordinates': cord}))
```

### Update:

#### Here is my new Python query:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_50000_melissa_joined_dropna - Copy2.csv",delimiter=',', na_values="nan")

# Output

with open(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_50000_melissa_joined_dropna - Copy2.csv", 'r') as csvin, open (r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_50000_melissa_joined_dropna - Copy3.csv", 'w', newline='') as out:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvin)
    fieldnames = csvreader.fieldnames + ["latitude","longitude","coordinates"]
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames)
    csvwriter.writeheader()

    # Iterating requests for each row
    for row in df.itertuples():
      output = client.geocode(str(row.addressline1) + ', ' + str(row.city) + ', ' + str(row.state) + ', ' + str(row.postalcode)).coords
      cord = '(' + str(output[0]) + ', '+ str(output[1]) + ')'

      for node, row1 in enumerate(csvreader, 38):
          csvwriter.writerow(dict(row1,latitude= output[0] % node))
      for node, row2 in enumerate(csvreader, 39):
          csvwriter.writerow(dict(row2,longitude = output[1] % node))
      for node, row3 in enumerate(csvreader, 40):
          csvwriter.writerow(dict(row3,coordinates= cord % node))
```

However, I get the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can more easily accomplish this by using more of pandas features.

Import the data from csv as you have been doing.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv("input_file.csv")
```

You can use `dataframe.apply(func, axis=1)` to apply a function to each row of a dataframe. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

```
def get_coords(row):
    return client.geocode(str(row.addressline1) + ', ' + str(row.city) + ', ' \
                   + str(row.state) + ', ' + str(row.postalcode)).coords

coords = df.apply(get_coords, axis=1)

df['latitide'] = coords.values[:,0]
df['longitude'] = coords.values[:,1]
df['coords'] = coords
```

You can then easily save the dataframe to csv using:

`df.to_csv('output_filename.csv')`

Hope this help.

p.s. code is untested but should be good :)

Comment: Thanks but I MUST use csvwriter.